flaskアプリからaspファイルを実行しwindowsログインユーザ名を取得する
実現したいこと
IISにFlaskアプリを設置し、アプリにアクセスしてきたユーザのwindowsログインユーザ名を取得したいです。
構成としては

IISにFlaskアプリを設置(app.py)
app.pyがメイン起動し、レンダリングによってindex.htmlを表示
index.html内のjavascriptからvbscriptが記述された.aspファイルを起動
.asp内でwindowsログインユーザ名を取得
取得したユーザ名をindex.htmlで受け取り表示

発生している問題・分からないこと
単純にHTML内にjsコードを記述し、aspファイルを呼び出すのみは実行できました。
ただ、本来やりたい事である、FlaskアプリからレンダリングされたHtmlファイルを基にAspを実行し戻り値を取得しようとするとaspファイル内のスクリプトテキストがそのまま戻り値として返ってきます。
index.htmlと.aspファイルは中身が同じ。違うのはFlaskからindexをレンダリングして表示するかどうかです。
index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>AJAX Example</title>
    <script>
        function callASP() {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("GET", "../static/getadid.asp", true);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
                    var response = xhr.responseText;
                    var parts = response.split(",");
                    var uid = parts[2]; // UIDは3番目の要素
                    console.log("取得" + parts);
                }
            };
            xhr.send();
        }

        window.onload = function() {
            callASP();
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="callAspFile()">Call ASP File</button>
    <div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>

    function callASP() {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", "../static/getadid.asp", true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
                var response = xhr.responseText;
                var parts = response.split(",");
                var uid = parts[2]; // UIDは3番目の要素
                console.log("取得" + parts);
            }
        };
        xhr.send();
    }

    window.onload = function() {
        callASP();
    };
</script>



    Call ASP File
    


.aspファイル（windowsログインユーザ名を取得する。中身はvbscript）
<%
On Error Resume Next
Dim vTxt, UIP, UID, fJob 

fJob = "UserData"                                           ' Jobフラグ
UIP = Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")                ' ユーザPC IPアドレス
UID = Split(Request.ServerVariables("AUTH_USER"),"\")(1)    ' ユーザADアカウント
'vTxt = fJob & "," & UIP & "," & UID & "," & Unam(UID)       ' 戻り値
vTxt = fJob & "," & UIP & "," & UID        ' 戻り値

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Response.Write "Error: " & Err.Description
Else
    Response.Write vTxt
End If

On Error GoTo 0
%>

app.py(Flaskメイン起動部分)
レンダリング部分のみでwebアプリの処理などは今回該当しないと思うので割愛してます。
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

修正後コード
回答でご提案いただいた内容で修正してみました
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>AJAX Example</title>
    <script>
        function callASP() {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("GET", "../static/getadid.asp", true);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
                    var response = xhr.responseText;
                    var parts = response.split(",");
                    var uid = parts[2]; // UIDは3番目の要素
                    console.log(parts);
                    // AJAXでFlaskアプリにデータを送信
                    sendDataToFlask(uid);
                }
            };
            xhr.send();
        }

        function sendDataToFlask(uid) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("POST", "/process_data", true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
                    document.getElementById("result").innerText = xhr.responseText;
                }
            };
            xhr.send(JSON.stringify({ "uid": uid }));
            console.log(uid);
        }

        window.onload = function() {
            callASP();
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="callASP()">Call ASP File</button>
    <div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>


from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/process_data', methods=['POST'])
def process_data():
    data = request.json
    uid = data.get('uid')
    
    # ここで、必要な処理を行う
    # 例えば、データベース検索や何かしらの計算など
    result = f"Received UID: {uid}"
    
    return jsonify(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)


結果の画面

おそらくテキストがそのまま返ってきています。
試しにparts要素をコンソール出力すると以下内容でした


「aspファイル内のスクリプトテキストがそのまま戻り値として返ってきます」ということは、iis で動いている asp アプリの getadid.asp に要求を出したことになってなくて、 getadid.asp  は静的ファイルとみなされてそのまま asp のコードが返ってきているのでは？　そもそも「flaskアプリからaspファイルを実行しwindowsログインユーザ名を取得する」ということはできないと思うのですが、何か勝算というかできる根拠はあるのでしょうか？

@WebSurfer
ご回答いただきありがとうございます。
私の理解としてもaspファイル内に記述しているvbscriptのコードが静的ファイルとしてみなされている事によって、スクリプトテキストが戻値になっている理解です。
経緯としては別の開発者が今回できている事同様にjsファイルからaspファイルを実行しwindowsユーザ名を取得しているのを拝見したので、私も同じようにjsファイルから実行し取得しようと思っておりました。
flask経由のjsから呼び出した事例を私も拝見したことないので、できる根拠はすいませんがないです。
今回のようにiisに設置したflaskアプリでwindowsユーザ名を取得する方法は他にないのでしょうか？また静的ファイルとしてみなされてしまう事を解消する事も出来ないのでしょうか？

「経緯としては別の開発者が今回できている事同様にjsファイルからaspファイルを実行しwindowsユーザ名を取得している」というのは iis で動いている asp アプリを直接ブラウザから要求して Windows 認証でログインし（または統合 Windows 認証の SSO でログイン済み）、その状態でブラウザから XMLHttpRequest で要求を出したということでは？　何にせよ flask から asp を要求したのでは何ともならないと思います。「別の開発者」に聞いてはいかがですか？

@WebSurfer
要約していただきありがとうございます。
まさしくその通りです。私も同じコード部分のみ活用し『 asp アプリを直接ブラウザから要求して Windows 認証でログインし（または統合 Windows 認証の SSO でログイン済み）、その状態でブラウザから XMLHttpRequest で要求を出した』は実行が出来ました。
別の開発者もわからないとの事でした。。
flaskへ値を渡せればいいんですが、、アドバイスいただきありがとうございます

index.htmlの中に、VBScriptを実行して得た情報をAJAX要求としてflaskアプリケーションにPOSTで送信し、アプリケーションから返ってきた結果をindex.htmlのどこか(id="result"のdiv?)に反映する処理とか、flaskアプリケーション側に該当するAJAX要求を処理して結果を返す処理が無いように見えます。それらを追加してみては？

@kunif
回答いただきありがとうございます
あまり分かっていない状態ですが、指摘いただいた内容を投稿に反映し、修正コードとして追記しました
結論としてはやはり、テキストがそのまま返ってきているかと思われます

そもそも今のVBScriptの内容なら別ファイルにせずHTMLの中に直接文字列として記述しても良いのでは？ それでわざわざダウンロードする手間が省けますし、送信される内容がおかしいとかの問題も減るのでは？

@kunif
知識なく申し訳ないですが、そんなことが可能なんでしょうか？
ダウンロードはしておらず、vbscriptの内容でwindowsユーザ名を取得しています

@kunif さんが何を根拠にそういう提案をしたのは分かりませんが、何にせよ可能ではないと思います。Windows 認証ですよね。統合 Windows 認証で、iis もユーザーが Active Directory ドメイン環境に属していて、ユーザーもドメインアカウントを持っていて、ユーザーがブラウザを立ち上げた時点で SSO で認証済みということなら分かりませんけど。

問題は、質問者さんがアクセスしようとしている asp ページのアプリが iis で動いているか、iis は AD ドメイン環境に属しているか、ユーザーは AD ドメイン環境に属しているかではないのですか？

@WebSurfer さん
ありがとうございます。
iisに置いたindex.htmlをadアカウントに属する別のユーザが開いた場合、aspファイルを呼び出してユーザ名の取得が出来ました。
問題はindex.htmlの呼び出しをflaskのapp.pyをメイン起動しindex.htmlをレンダリングした際に同様のコードであっても静的ファイルとみなし、aspのスクリプトがまるまる戻ってくることです。
app.pyを起動した際に同様の事が出来ないのであればと思い、現在別の方法を模索しています

かなり誤解していたようです。クライアントPCのWebブラウザ上で受け取ったVBScriptを実行してログインユーザー名を取得するのだと思っていました。

@kunif さん私の説明が拙く誤解をまねき、申し訳ないです。何か方法がないかもしあれば、またよろしくお願いします

https://qiita.com/mako1047/items/65291ad41041e09f337e
上記記事で実装し、自己解決できました
色々と回答していただきありがとうございました！

もし解決したのであれば、コメント欄で終わらせずに自己回答として投稿してください。ただコメントに書いただけだとこの質問は未解決のままになってしまいます。

FlaskからC#経由でスクリプトを実行し戻り値でwindowsユーザ名を取得しました。
以下リンク先を参照し、dotnetのインストール等もろもろ同じように実装すると問題なく『ドメイン名/windowsユーザ名』で取得できるのを確認済み。
参考:
Python Flask のアプリへ Windows 認証ユーザを連携したい - Qiita
※業務で活用している部分があるためコードは割愛します。上記リンク先の内容実装で問題ないです。
